# Can't view collection of data in laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

i returned a collection of two tables of data with join query as a collection and group by user id. i want to view it on a html table.
 My data array looks like this. How can i show this all data into html table view using laravel blade.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you are sending the collection to your blade template. You can use a foreach loop to iterate through array:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $item->fname}}</td>
       <td>{{ $item->lname }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It should work just fine, as long as you properly passed `$items` to the view.

Comment: what does your controller method look like that is creating the collection?

Comment: $assign = DB::table('users')
                    ->join('assign_jobs', 'users.user_id', '=', 'assign_jobs.user_id')
                    ->select('users.fname', 'users.lname', 'assign_jobs.*')
                    ->where('users.status', 'complete')
                    ->get();

        $details = $assign->groupBy('user_id');

Comment: @WebDev1125 shows me this error Property [fname] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: That means you're trying to do `$items->fname`, not `$item->fname`. Individual items *within* the collection have first names; the collection itself does not.

Comment: in the loop can you dump the $item? you may be able to access [fname] as $item['fname']